# Finding "bad email addresses" in a mailbox

Tags: email, header, smtp, pop3

I have programmatic access to a POP3 mailbox plus access to archived emails stored in a database. My objective to to find out bad email addresses -- the email addresses from which emails were returned (bounced) with status or messages such as:

- Undeliverable mail
- Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
- Undelivered mail returned to sender
- Emails from people such as mailer-daemon or postmaster

Is there are way to  filter out such emails without using "heuristics"? Its easy to scan the subject for words like "undeliverable" or senders such as "mailer-daemon" but I want a better solution, if any.

Note that I have access to mail headers for all POP3/database archived emails. Is there some header that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Some mail servers implement [RFC 3464](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3464). Those that do will typically generate Delivery Status Notifications with a message header Content-Type of multipart/report and three component parts (text/plain, message/delivery-status and message/rfc822). So you could detect those characteristics of the message and process accordingly. The message will generally look like this:

From: "Mail Delivery System" <MAILER-DAEMON@example.com>
Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status

Content-Type: text/plain
A human readable explanation of the Delivery Status Notification.

Content-Type: message/delivery-status
A structured machine readable reason for the Delivery Status Notification.

Content-Type: message/rfc822
The original message.

For those mail servers that generate Delivery Status Notifications in an unstructured format, it is probably still necessary to detect their notifications by analysing the text of the From: and Subject: message headers.